# How to stop BLUEJ from character to character compiling

Tags: java, bluej, auto-compile

The newer updates of Java Compiling platform **BLUEJ** works on a character to character compilation which makes it slower to type efficiently because when you type syntax in a large Program it compiles the full program on the addition of every new character which makes the updation of input character in the program slower and hence the typing Lags.
Is there any way to stop the compiler from **auto compiling** the code on every character/syntax addition and just compile *after some specific time* or when the user presses compile button like it was in *previous version* where the code gets auto compiled after a certain time.

Comment: BlueJ is a Great IDE which provides fast compiling and few other features which makes it more prefrable to use.